# The connectors does not refresh when the target is dragged

Tags: jsplumb

I meet a problem when I am trying to add connectors dynamically, but I meet a problem. When a link was dragged from the source to the target, the connector move when the source is dragged, that is good. But the connector does not move when the target is dragged. I do not know why!
the URL is:http://sanghuihui.lewoqu.com/test/home/home/dom2.html!
please help me.Thank you very much!

Comment: `jsPlumb.repaintEverything()` http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/utilities.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jsPlumb.repaintEverything()`:

You can add this snippet in you code:

```
$('#Mywindow1').on('mousedown', function() 
{ 
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything() 
});
$('#Mywindow2').on('mousedown', function() 
{ 
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything() 
});
```

Cheers :)